# 3D object detection methods

Tags: object, 3d, detection

I am new to the area, and I would like to know what are the main methods to detect 3D real objects. I have searched on Google, find PCL, and edge based methods as well. I am wondering that is anybody know any paper or article that introduce this kind of thing?

Comment: What do you mean by 3D object detection?

Comment: The context is that I am undertaking a task which is to capture 3D real object within AR/VR environment. So in this context, "3D object detection" means to capture a real 3D object, then add its 3D model to the AR/VR environment.